# Google Streetview API returns irrelevant images

Tags: google-street-view

I would like to incorporate street level images in an Android app.  My first port of call has been the Google Streetview API.  Much to my surprise, the images returned often lack relevancy.  Here are a couple off examples

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=480x300&location=49.602363,6.133369&key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

which corresponds to the street address: 45, avenue de la Gare, Luxembourg

which returns what appears to be the inside of a bedroom in a hotel.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=480x300&location=49.847802,6.098523&key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

which returns the image of two people walking near a field.  Contrary to what I thought was standard Google policy the people are clearly recognizable.

In both cases I notice that the images are not by Google.

Is there anything that can be done to limit the images by source so I only deliver imagery taken by Google which I assume is more reliable?  Alternately, are there other sources of street level imagery?  I have looked at Mapillary but found the imagery lacking and at Here maps which appears to have an overly complicated API